# Only Displaying Dialog Box on First Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, popup

I currently have a dialog box that automatically displays each time the page is loaded. However, I have functionalities such as a search so when a user searches for an entry, it will then display the popup box again since the page is being loaded again.

How can I get it so that the dialog box only displays the first time the page is loaded?

Here is my HTML code for the dialog box:

```
<!-- Dialog box -->
<div id="dialog-form" title="Instructions">
  <form>
    <fieldset>        

      <ul>
          <li>These are instructions</li><br>
          <li>that should be displayed</li><br>
          <li>inside the dialog box</li><br>
          <li>on the first load only</li>
      </ul>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( function() {   

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        OK: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: You could try using sessionStorage to set a variable after it is shown the first time, and every time before showing the dialog check to see if it has already been set.  If so, don't show it again.

Comment: Can you show your full code (the page that is loaded and then re-loaded)? If it is PHP, you could pass a flag when you do a search that the JS can reference on whether to show the dialog or not. If the page is a single page that doesn't refresh, you could just use a JS global variable and set that on init to prevent the dialog from showing again. Session storage variables would also work.

Comment: you can use cookies... issue is when user has disabled them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

When first time you show the popup, mark this in browser's sessionStorage by setting some value using `sessionStorage.setItem("variableName", "value");`.

Now, add a check before you show the popup that checks whether that value is already set in browser's sessionStorage by using `sessionStorage.getItem("variableName");`.

`sessionStorage` keeps variables in browser's memory until you close the browser tab/window. So, it works fine across page loads.

```
$( function() {   
    var popupDisplayed = sessionStorage.getItem("popupDisplayed");
    if( popupDisplayed !== "true" ){
    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        OK: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });

    // mark this in sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.setItem("popupDisplayed", "true" );
   }//if not found in sessionStorage
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

If you need to do only for one session, use `SessionStorage` as described by Mohit.

If it should be stored permanently in the user's browser, use `LocalStorage`

Use `Local Storage` to check if a popup has been shown or not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isshown = localStorage.getItem('isshown');
    if (isshown== null) {
        localStorage.setItem('isshown', 1);

        // Show popup here
        var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
         OK: function() {
         dialog.dialog( "close" );
         }
       }
     }); 
    }
});
```

This will show popup only once

More info on using Local Storage is [Here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: We can use localStorage but it will prevent the popup from being shown even if the user comes back to it later sometime e.g. after some days. Depends on the requirement then though.

Comment: Thanks @MohitBhardwaj, I thought op wants to show popup only and only  once.