# How to make a Modal Window popup only on first visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a modal window that pops up when you visit a certain page.  The visitor has to choose either I agree or I disagree.  I need a nice little jquery script that will remember who visited the page before and agreed so the modal won't pop up every time they visit the page.

Can someone recommend a good script to use?  Here is the code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
         <p style="text-align:center">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br />
tollit insolens abhorreant no sed<br />
<strong>Et alia cetero</strong>
</p>

<h3>IMPORTANT</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque persecuti elaboraret pro at. Qui dicat 
dicit nostrud ex, vix id debet detraxit. Eam nostrud probatus dissentias 
ne, ollit insolens abhorreant no sed. Ius cibo denique ea. Et alia cetero 
efficiantur mel, vix facer sententiae no.
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque persecuti elaboraret pro at. Qui dicat 
dicit nostrud ex, vix id debet detraxit:
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque persecuti elaboraret pro at. Qui dicat 
dicit nostrud ex, vix id debet detraxit. Eam nostrud probatus dissentias ne, 
tollit insolens abhorreant no sed. Ius cibo denique ea. Et alia cetero 
efficiantur mel, vix facer sententiae no.
</p>

<p>

</p>


    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>

</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> 
    <a href="#modal-one" class="btn1">Agree</a>
    <a href="#modal-one" class="btn1">Disagree</a>


    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap"></div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: you're going to want to set a cookie when they agree or disagree, then read that cookie when determining whether or not to show the modal

Comment: or use localStorage

Comment: where is your try-code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only Displaying Dialog Box on First Load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051731/only-displaying-dialog-box-on-first-load)

Answer (score 4):

On first visit plant a `cookie` or a value in `local storage` of user browser and on every visit check if that `cookie` or `local storage` value is there then do not show the modal/popup again.

Local storage ex:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);  // set
localStorage.getItem(key);         // get
```

Comment: just as a note - I prefer using localStorage over cookies 100% of the time - much easier to use, and cookies are vulnerable (that being said not sure the security of local storage)

Answer (score 2):

You can set Items into the local storage via:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

and reading is easy:

```
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Now grep a keyword for you "first-time-visit" and just ask the local storage :) Keep in ming, that a user can clear his local storage.